# VS code shows who modified the line

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

How to see who modified the line with git on vs code?

[image]

Comment: That's provided by various extensions, including GitLens, as long as you use Git

Comment: with GitLens use the **File Annotations** button in the top right menu of the editor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a VS Code extension called "GitLens". This extension shows you in the editor who made the last changes to this line. It also has a ton of other features.

Comment: i would like the editor to color the lines number for changes

Comment: It does this already. for example, if you add a new line of code, at the left side of the codeline, a green bar will appear. Meaning that this part of the code is new. And if you delete/change a line of code, the bar becomes yellow & black striped

Answer (score 0):

I also found git blame which is more discreet
[image: example of git blame]

Answer (score 0):

Also the plugin GitToolBox provides this "blade editor inline" functionality.